# Creating Actions for Personal use only

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

My house has an home automation system from the 1960's that I have managed to tap into.  I've been able to setup an interface which allows me to write adapters for various technologies such as Node Red, Alexa, and now Google Assistent.

Given that this will only ever work with my house, I see no reason to make public Smart Home Actions.  On Alexa's side, I can let these services stay in a Development state indefinitely which has worked great for the last 6 months.  On Google's side, however, the FAQ says (https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/faq):

> Q: How often do I need to run *gactions test*?
>
> A: *gactions test* needs be refreshed every 3 days. After 3 days the test agent will disappear from mobile-HomeControl settings. If you run into this, just run *gaction test* again.

Therefore, I was wondering **what they best way is to make a PERSONAL Google Actions service?**  Of course, the obvious method would be to script and schedule the gactions call to keep testing alive but I would hope there was a better way to support this!

Additional details:  I'm using Amazon's OAuth service for sign-in.  This way, I can validate the Amazon ClientID, UserID, etc. through the AccesssToken Google passes in for authorization.  Therefore, I could theoretically run this publicly without any issues but I would need to figure out how Google could review it for testing purposes!  I don't need some Google employee turning on and off my lights while the Google Maps car drive by to verify the change... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a script to call gaction periodically. 
Publishing it would unnecessarily pollute the Actions directory. Also, they'll make you jump through hoops for "brand verification" and other restrictions they have for naming invocation terms.
If you did publish it, you give them a temporary account for verification purposes and disable the account when published. They would be randomly controlling the lights during the verification period though which can be up to a week!

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I'm leaning towards as well.  This is definitely one area where the Alexa system has the upper hand!